# CRM 2011 Case Queue audit history

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to Audit "Case" queue history. We can audit field history but not on relationship entity. So if case is assigned to Queue "Queue1" and after couple of days if the case is assigned to another queue "Queue2". So how can we track queue history for the case, like how much time it stays in Queue1 and queue2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we enable audit for Queueitem, We can see audit history in following way.

To see Case Audit history.

CASE > QueueItemDetails(Ribbon) > Audit History.

Database table: Audit
query : SELECT * FROM audit WHERE objectid LIKE ''